# how to make Localization with Getx if there is parameter in the text

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

if the text like this:

```
           Text(
              'Put something ${widget.profileA} might like'.tr,        
            ),
```

Here is the code for the translation example:

```
class Language extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          'Put something ${widget.profileA} might like': 'some translation', 
        };
      };
}
```

My question is since there is a parameter `${widget.profileA}` in the text, is there a good solution to translate whole sentence with this parameter? thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation of GetX explains well how you can do that here: https://pub.dev/packages/get#internationalization

> Using translation with parameters
>
> ```
> Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
>     'en_US': {
>         'logged_in': 'logged in as @name with email @email',
>     },
>     'es_ES': {
>        'logged_in': 'iniciado sesión como @name con e-mail @email',
>     } };
>
> Text('logged_in'.trParams({   
>   'name': 'Jhon',
>   'email':'jhon@example.com'
> }));
> ```

So for your example:

```
class Language extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          'Put something @profile might like': 'some translation with @profile', 
        };
      };
}
```

and then

```
Text('Put something @profile might like'.trParams({
  'profile': widget.profileA,
}));
```